# Spring security Custom filter not getting called

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I want to write custom filter for token verification on each request in Spring app.

For that I have written below code in spring security xml but custom filter is not getting call. could anyone can suggest on this why this is happening?

I don't have any login form we have just plain REST services. So not sure on which position I have to give the custom filter.

I am  using custom-filter position  as below.

```
<http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />  
    <custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="jwtAuthenticationFilter"/>         
</http> 

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="jwtAuthenticationProvider" /> 
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.test.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" /> 
<bean id="jwtAuthenticationProvider" class="com.test.JwtAuthenticationProvider" />
```

Comment: Its rosolve now, I forgot to add configuration in web.xml for security  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
 
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>//*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Comment: can you take your answer and either (1) append your question text... or (2) actually add an answer?  the xml in a comment is hard to read.